# REDCap surveys not being sent out via Twilio

Tags: twilio, datediff, redcap

[image: automated survey invite settings]

[image: survey invitation log]

We are having some trouble with receiving scheduled surveys via text using Twilio and are unsure whether it is an issue with the logic we are using to send out the texts or an issue receiving the texts. Below, I attached a screenshot of the survey invitation log. The current settings that we are using for the automated survey invitations appear to be working here, as we can see the scheduled invitations in the survey invitation log. However, we are not receiving these scheduled texts. Because they are not actually being sent out, they are not showing up when I click “view past invitations” and no error messages are showing up for those that were sent. I also attached a screenshot of the automated survey invitation settings we were hoping to use. We will be sending out this survey every day for 49 days, changing the datediff function to the respective number of days. Does anyone have advice on where we may be going wrong (e.g., if logic won’t work in step 3 or if this is a Twilio issue)?

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, I've not used REDCap before. Is there somewhere you can inspect what happened when it tried to send an SMS message? Are you able to send test SMS messages without scheduling to make sure that you have set up your account correctly? Have you checked your Twilio console for any error logs in sending messages?

Comment: In the survey invitation log in REDCap, there are no errors shown which makes me think it is a Twilio issue. Our IS department only has access to the Twilio console to see the error logs, so we are unable to. We have sent out test SMS messages without scheduling them and are receiving those ok. It seems to be an issue only when scheduled.

Comment: I think your best first move is to talk with your IS department and view the logs. If there errors, then you can use that knowledge to work out what's going on. If the messages aren't there at all, then perhaps the issue is in the REDCap integration.

Comment: Consider asking your institution's REDCap admin to post this question on the "REDCap Community website".